# Flutter sliver list with a side container as long as sliver list length

Tags: flutter, dart

I am using a custom scroll view for scrolling. I want to make sliver list where a container has a sliver list length.

Here is the picture what I want to achieve

[image]

Here is my json api response

```
{
    "getNotices": [
        {
            "id": "d7dc04b4-725a-407d-93b8-eff16de84c4d",
            "title": "Result Published! First annual Examination result was published",
            "description": "<p>Dear all,<br></p><p>In celebration of Eid Al-Fitr, our office will be closed from [date] to [date]. We will resume our regular business hours on [date].</p><p>We would like to take this opportunity to wish all of our Muslim colleagues and clients a blessed and joyous Eid Al-Fitr. May this occasion bring you and your loved ones happiness, peace, and prosperity.</p><p>Please note that any urgent matters can still be directed to [contact person or department]. We apologize for any inconvenience this may cause and appreciate your understanding.</p><p>Thank you.</p><p>[Your Name or Company Name]</p>",
            "pdf": "student/1payUwKS69AHX9pxVEv35E.pdf",
            "created_at": "2023-05-05T14:34:57.739Z"
        },
        {
            "id": "c97a3228-2fd6-4903-9cc9-127994b65f96",
            "title": "Upcoming Eid Holiday and Summer Holiday announcement!",
            "description": "<p>Dear Student,</p><p>In celebration of Eid Al-Fitr, our schooll will be closed from 12 April to 30 April. We will resume our regular class hours on 31 April.</p><p>We would like to take this opportunity to wish all of our Muslim colleagues and clients a blessed and joyous Eid Al-Fitr. May this occasion bring you and your loved ones happiness, peace, and prosperity.</p><p>Please note that any urgent matters can still be directed to [contact person or department]. We apologize for any inconvenience this may cause and appreciate your understanding.</p><p>Thank you.</p><p>My School Name</p>",
            "pdf": "student/25pLxKS1eKrbzucstF8cRv.pdf",
            "created_at": "2023-05-05T14:01:30.577Z"
        }
    ]
}
```

How can I build this?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.